# show push notification only when app is not running in cordova android

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, chrome-gcm

I have a push notification integrated with GCM It's working fine. Whenever push notification comes then it redirected to specific page when user outside the application. But whenever user inside the application then it also redirect the specific  page when notification come. So i don't want to redirect to specific page when user inside the. Please help me...

Here is my code...For Push Notification

```html
var pushNotification;
function onDeviceReady() {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>deviceready event received</li>');
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>backbutton event received</li>');
        if ($.mobile.activePage.is('#indexPage')) {
            
            e.preventDefault();
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);
    try {
         pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, { "senderID": "XXXXXXXXX", "ecb": "onNotification" });  // required!
        }
        //else {
        //    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, { "badge": "true", "sound": "true", "alert": "true", "ecb": "onNotificationAPN" }); // required!
        //}
    }
    catch (err) {
        txt = "There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt += "Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }
}
// handle GCM notifications for Android
function onNotification(e) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');
    switch (e.event) {
        case 'registered':
            if (e.regid.length > 0) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
                localStorage.setItem("REGID", e.regid);
                console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
            }
            break;
        case 'message':
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
            if (e.foreground) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                window.localStorage.setItem("push_que", e.payload.id);
                window.localStorage.setItem("recordId",e.payload.recordId);
                var push_que = e.payload.id;
                var soundfile = e.soundname || e.payload.sound;
                var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + soundfile);
                my_media.play();
            }
            else { 
                if (e.coldstart) {
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                    window.localStorage.setItem("push_que", e.payload.id);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("recordId",e.payload.recordId);
                }
                else
                    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
                window.localStorage.setItem("push_que", e.payload.id);
                window.localStorage.setItem("recordId",e.payload.recordId);

            }
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
          
            //android only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
            //amazon-fireos only
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> TIMESTAMP: ' + e.payload.timeStamp + '</li>');
            onResume();
            break;
        case 'error':
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
            break;
        default:
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
            break;
    }
    pushNotify();
}
function successHandler(result) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>success:' + result + '</li>');
}
function errorHandler(error) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>error:' + error + '</li>');
}
```

Here is onResume() method which helps to redirect specific page

```html
function onResume() {
    //toast('App resumed', 'short');

    var que_push = window.localStorage.getItem("push_que");
    if (que_push == "inboxDetails") {
        $.mobile.changePage("#inboxDetails");
        window.localStorage.removeItem("push_que");
    }
    if (que_push == "trackComplaintTable") {
        var recordId = window.localStorage.getItem("recordId");
        showtrackcomplaintdetail(recordId);
        $.mobile.changePage("#trackComplaintTable");
        window.localStorage.removeItem("push_que");
    }
    // if a number is sent  open a specific news article calling a specific funcion that loads the "articles"
    if (que_push != "inboxDetails" && que_push != "trackComplaintTable" && que_push != "") {
        window.localStorage.removeItem("push_que");
    }

}
```

Comment: what will do the function pushNotify();

Comment: In this function i call the web service which is insert mobile device key in to database

Comment: #Homen i am using cordova pushPlugin

Comment: I have modified the code in the first first block. replaced the onResume() function inside the else block. Please have a look on it and give a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass  **onResume() function** in else block of  if **(e.foreground) statement **  inside   **onNotification(e)**  function